# how to combine logistic and poisson in a multivariate model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, poisson, glmmtmb, multivariate-time-series

How do I write a multivariate zero-inflated model using both the logistic and poisson regression methods in one model?

The results should look something like this:
[image]

In this article, this is done by PROC NLMIXED in SAS9.3. How can I do this with a glmmTMB package in r?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zeroinfl` function from the `svyVGAM` package.

See a vignette on its use here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svyVGAM/vignettes/zeroinfl.html